# jQuery FadeIn for append element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanto to fadein only the append element

I try with this

```
$("ul#content-wall").append(msg.template).hide().fadeIn(300).promise().done(function () {
});
```

or

```
$("ul#content-wall").hide().append(msg.template).fadeIn('normal').promise().done(function () {
```

But Hide and fade in Whole container, i want hide and fadein Only

```
'msg.template'
```

Thanks

**Update**

i try to this

```
$(msg.template).hide().appendTo('#content-wall').fadeIn(300).promise().done(function () {});
```

But i have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li class="result_search">168foo</li>
```

my console.log(msg.template)

```
<li class="result_search"> 168 foo </li>
```

my console.dir(msg.template)

```
   <li class="result_search">
        168
        foo
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo) to get back the references to the newly appended elements and then animate it

```
$(msg.template).hide().appendTo('#content-wall').fadeIn(300).promise().done(function () {});
```

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append) returns the reference to the container element to which the new elements are added.

Comment: thanks, i have a problem my msg.template is 
`<li class="result_search"> 168 foo </li>`

`Uncaught TypeError: Object 

    <li class="result_search">
        168
        foo
    </li>


 has no method 'hide' `

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(msg.template).appendTo('ul#contentwall').hide().fadeIn(300).promise().done(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$(msgtemplate).appendTo($("ul#content-wall")).hide().fadeIn(500);

Comment: like this ? 
`$(msg.template).appendTo('#content-wall').hide().fadeIn(300).promise().done(function () {`

i have this error 
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

        function appendData() {
            
            var template = "<li>Test Data</li>";
           $(template).appendTo($("ul#ulwall")).hide().fadeIn(500).promise().done(function() {
            });
            

        }
    </script>

    <ul id="ulwall">
    </ul>
<input type="button" onclick="return appendData()" value="append"/>

Comment: thanks i have another "error " maybe Bug ! 
http://jsfiddle.net/PZKZ2/
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

With your help and with the help of a user IRC (Cork):

```
$($.parseHTML(msg.template)).filter('*').appendTo('ul#content-wall').hide().fadeIn(300).promise().done(function () {}
```

I had an error without filter

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

Because first element in the array is a text node

```
fadeIn do $(template).eq(0) [textnode] .fade => crash
fadeIn do $(template).eq(1) [li] .fade => would work
```

Filter do (Corks said):
 it takes the array and loops through and gives you a new array with the elements that matched the selector,and as textNodes doesn't match selectors it should work with *

**Update**
With jQuery 1.10.1 i haven't error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```